# Signification de « sans travail » dans les Essais de Montaigne

Tags: littérature, moyen-français

Dans le troisième livre des *Essais*, Montaigne écrit :

> Qui ne voit que j’ay pris une route par laquelle, sans cesse et sans travail, j’iray autant qu’il y aura d’ancre et de papier au monde ?

Comment faut-il ici comprendre « sans travail » ? La rédaction des *Essais* demande au contraire beaucoup de travail. Faut-il entendre cette expression d'une manière qui semble très moderne : en tant que rentier, Montaigne est « sans travail » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je comprends ***travail*** comme ***effort*** ici :

> Sans cesse et sans effort (infatigablement).

On retrouve la même expression dans *Des cannibales* (Livre 1, chap. 31):

> *Ils ne contestent pas à d’autres la conquête de nouvelles terres, car ils jouissent encore de cette fécondité naturelle qui leur procure **sans travail** et sans peine toutes les choses nécessaires, et en telle abondance, qu’ils n’ont que faire d’agrandir leur territoire.*

où là aussi, ***sans travail*** indique que les cannibales disposent des ressources de la nature ***sans** (avoir à fournir d') **effort***.

Comment: Avec *tripalium* originel comme source : sans douleur ou plutôt sans souffrance qui inclue la douleur qui peut naître d'un travail/effort ininterrompu. — PS : j'ai découvert que ***a**ncre* était un synonyme de ***e**ncre*, de nos jours se pose la question : comment *l'ancora* latine peut-elle arrêter l'écriture ?

Comment: @Personne L'étymologie *tripalium* est parfois contestée. Je la trouve aussi un peu tirée par les cheveux (une autre torture). Relier *travail* à *travée* et *entraver* semble plus logique. PS:  Quand on effraie un poulpe mandarin, il lui arrive de jeter l'ancre (de Chine bien sûr).

Comment: Le poulpe japonais https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_R%C3%AAve_de_la_femme_du_p%C3%AAcheur … encre, s'ancre aussi dans les rêves.

Comment: Cette réponse est très convaincante. C'est dommage car j'appréciais l'idée de Montaigne en rentier éclairé. Comme de coutume, je vais tout de même attendre quelques jours avant de l'accepter.